# How to expand a two dimentioanl array

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

is there easy way that we can pad zero's around two dimensional ruby array ?

```
1 1 4
1 6 9
2 6 5
```

to this

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 4 0
0 1 6 9 0
0 2 6 5 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Could you turn that text into Ruby code, please?

Comment: @Stefan wants you to write the example's input and output as Ruby objects. I agree. That makes it clearer and allows readers to cut and paste to test their code. You could write, for example, `arr = [[1, ,1, 4], [1, 6, 9], [2, 6, 5]]` and show the desired return value is `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 4, 0],...]`. Assigning a variable (here `arr`) to the input object is not essential, but it allows readers to reference the variable in answers and comments without having to define it. Please edit to make the necessary changes. You might even get the hold on your question removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [[1, 1, 4], 
       [1, 6, 9], 
       [2, 6, 5]]
```

The following avoids the need to check for boundary cases.

```
Array.new(arr.size+2) { |i| Array.new(arr.first.size+2, 0) }.tap { |a|
  arr.size.times { |i| arr.first.size.times { |j| a[i+1][j+1] = arr[i][j] } } }

  #=> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 1, 1, 4, 0],
  #    [0, 1, 6, 9, 0],
  #    [0, 2, 6, 5, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

See the docs for the class method [Array::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-c-new) and the instance method [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-tap).

Answer (score 1):

The following Ruby onliner should do the trick.

```
array = [[1, 1, 4], 
         [1, 6, 9], 
         [2, 6, 5]] 

result = [Array.new(array.size + 2, 0)] + array.map{|subarr| [0] + subarr + [0]} + [Array.new(array.size + 2, 0)]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Array.new(array[0].size + 2, 0)]` would be better

Comment: @Santhosh Thanks, I will change it accordingly.